# How to get list of fields instead of one field in `Mymodel.objects.values()`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

in Django models you can filter the field that you want but how to get a list of fields instead of one field.

```
print(list(MyModel.objects.all()))
# returns this [<ChangeTrack: ChangeTrack object (1)>, <ChangeTrack: ChangeTrack object (2)>, <ChangeTrack: ChangeTrack object (3)>,]

print(list(MyModel.objects.values('id')))
#returns this [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 4}, {'id': 5}, {'id': 6}, {'id': 7}, {'id': 8}, {'id': 9}, ]

# I want to use `request.GET.get('fields')` in django views
print(list(MyModel.objects.values(request.GET.get('fields')))
print(list(MyModel.objects.values('id', 'username')))
# to return [{'id': 1,'username':'ali'}, {'id': 2,'username':'jack'}, {'id': 3,'username':'any'}, {'id': 4,'username':'more'}, {'id': 5,'username':'john'}, ... ]
```

**error** `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'id,username' into field. Choices are: action_type, by, by_id, date_created, deleted, field_target, field_value, id, model_target, username, related_to, related_to_id`

Comment: Can you be more clear? A sample required output vs current output would be helpful.

Comment: You can work with `MyModel.objects.values()` to get data of all (concrete) fields.

Comment: Doesn't `MyModel.objects.values('id', 'username')` already do what you want? See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#values). Or if you want to _dynamically pass_ a list of field names to it you can write `MyModel.objects.values(*your_list)`

Comment: Aha the thing is I am trying to do it in the view like this `data.values(request.GET.get('fields'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass needed sequence of fields to the value method like this:

```py
MyModel.objects.values('id', 'username')
```

Also take a look at the `values_list` and `only` methods, them could be useful too.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Answer (score 1):

From your error `Cannot resolve keyword 'id,username'` I can see that you send comma separated field names in the GET parameter `fields`. You can use the steps below to do what you want:

1. Split the string on commas and make it a list. Also strip any potential spaces just for good measure:

   ```
   field_names = []
   if 'fields' in request.GET:
       field_names = [i.strip() for i in request.GET.get('fields').split(',')]
   ```
2. Pass these `field_names` to `.values` by using *unpacking*:

   ```
   print(list(MyModel.objects.values(*field_names)))
   ```

---

> **Note**: This can give you errors considering the user may pass incorrect field names. You might want to consider using `Form` classes
> and using [`MultipleChoiceField` [Django
> docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this -

```
MyModel.objects.values('id', 'username').all()
```

`all()` method of model manager will return the list of all the objects like -

```
[{'id': 1,'username':'ali'}, {'id': 2,'username':'jack'}, {'id': 3,'username':'any'}, {'id': 4,'username':'more'}, {'id': 5,'username':'john'}, ... ]
```